Should I cast a Custom Entry?
Elaborating on the example given by the refman on Custom Entries, I get into a conundrum: should I or should I not cast in the notation for delimiting subexpressions (I mean, the e custom expr rule)?

Case 1: if I don't cast e as per the refman's example, I get an e : ?A in the last Check, which looks to me quite undesirable (isn't it?).

Case 2: if I do cast e, I get my expected e : Expr in the last Check, but now the notation works only in the context of the delimiters, as can be seen in the first Check...  This I find better than the previous case, still not ideal.


Is there a way to fix the code to achieve both desiderata?  Otherwise, is there some canonical or typical way to go about this?
Inductive Expr :=
| One : Expr
| Mul : Expr -> Expr -> Expr
| Add : Expr -> Expr -> Expr.

Declare Custom Entry expr.

(* Case 1: -------- *)
 Notation "[ e ]" := e
  (e custom expr at level 2).
(* Case 2: -------- *)
(* Notation "[ e ]" := (e : Expr)
  (e custom expr at level 2). *)

Notation "1" := One (in custom expr at level 0).
Notation "x y" := (Mul x y) (in custom expr at level 1,
  left associativity).
Notation "x + y" := (Add x y) (in custom expr at level 2,
  left associativity).
Notation "( x )" := x (in custom expr, x at level 2).
Notation "{ x }" := x (in custom expr, x constr).
Notation "x" := x (in custom expr at level 0, x ident).

(* Here Case 1 seems better: ##### *)
Check (fun x y z => eq_refl) :
  forall x y z, [x (y z)] = Mul x (Mul y z).
(* Case 1: --------
  (fun x y z : Expr => eq_refl)
    : forall x y z : Expr, [x (y z)] = [x (y z)]
    : forall x y z : Expr, [x (y z)] = [x (y z)]
*)
(* Case 2: --------
  (fun x y z : Expr => eq_refl)
    : forall x y z : Expr, [x (y z)] = Mul x (Mul y z)
    : forall x y z : Expr, Mul x (Mul y z) = Mul x (Mul y z)
*)

(* Here Case 2 seems better: ##### *)
Check (fun x => eq_refl) : forall e, [e] = e.
(* Case 1: --------
  (fun x : ?A => eq_refl)
    : forall e : ?A, e = e
    : forall e : ?A, e = e
  where ?A : [e : ?A |- Type] (e cannot be used)
*)
(* Case 2: --------
  (fun x : Expr => eq_refl)
    : forall e : Expr, [e] = e
    : forall e : Expr, e = e
*)


(* This code works in Coq 8.18.0 *)

Inductive Expr :=
| One : Expr
| Mul : Expr -> Expr -> Expr
| Add : Expr -> Expr -> Expr.

Declare Custom Entry expr.
Declare Scope Expr_scope.
Delimit Scope Expr_scope with Expr.
Bind Scope Expr_scope with Expr.
Open Scope Expr_scope.

Notation "[ e ]" := e
  (e custom expr at level 2) : Expr_scope.
(*
If `e` is ensured to be of `Expr`,
then `e` is denoted by the Custom Entry `expr`.
*)
Notation "[ e ]" := (e : Expr).
(*
The above is the default interpretation.
We must cast `e` into `Expr` to achieve print:
  (fun x : Expr => eq_refl)
    : forall e : Expr, [e] = e
    : forall e : Expr, e = e
*)

Notation "1" := One (in custom expr at level 0).
Notation "x y" := (Mul x y) (in custom expr at level 1,
  left associativity).
Notation "x + y" := (Add x y) (in custom expr at level 2,
  left associativity).
Notation "( x )" := x (in custom expr, x at level 2).
Notation "{ x }" := x (in custom expr, x constr).
Notation "x" := x (in custom expr at level 0, x ident).

Check (fun x y z => eq_refl) :
  forall x y z, [x (y z)] = Mul x (Mul y z).
(*
  (fun x y z : Expr => eq_refl)
    : forall x y z : Expr, [x (y z)] = [x (y z)]
    : forall x y z : Expr, [x (y z)] = [x (y z)]
*)

Check (fun x => eq_refl) : forall e, [e] = e.
(*
  (fun x : Expr => eq_refl)
    : forall e : Expr, [e] = e
    : forall e : Expr, e = e
*)


This soultion is my own, but I don't know why it works. It was found by just trial-and-error. Thus, if there is anyone who can explain how it works, please edit my answer.

Indeed that works, thanks very much!  In fact, AFAICT, we do not even need the (Delimit, Bind and) Open Scope: Declare Scope then the two definitions of the delimiting notation seem to do it.  --  I find especially perplexing that Custom Entries in the refman come before Scoping and are not connected to it, despite without it they get the job only partially done... or so it seems.
